# rsyslog to h2 database connector

Tags: h2, rsyslog

In rsyslog I've created a template for a database insert statement called *NV* and I write these insert statements to a file *ys_nv_haproxy.log* as follows

```
if $programname startswith 'haproxy' and $msg contains '/nextVehicles'    then action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/ys_nv_haproxy.log" template="NV")
```

Then when the log is being rotated on a daily basis I set up *postrotate* to load the insert statements from *ys_nv_haproxy.log* into the h2 database as follows:

```
java -cp "$dir/h2-1.4.196.jar:$H2DRIVERS:$CLASSPATH" org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:7002/rsyslogdb -user rsysloguser -password rsyslogpwd -script /var/log/ys_nv_haproxy.log.1
```

where I can view them using the h2 browser. Obviously with this it is a bulk load and I have to wait until the next day to view the previous days data.

Questions is is there an easy way of using the template *NV* to log the data immediately in the h2 database as soon as it appears in rsyslog. I have seen rsyslog output modules for mysql and postgres and am looking for something similar that will work with my h2 setup.

Comment: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/idx_output.html  Read this. These are the output modules available in rsyslog.

Comment: I saw that but there is no driver for h2 with omlibdbi

Comment: so that answers your question then. You can create an issue on their github repo and ask them about a solution, https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues

Comment: Have logged an issue and will wait and see what comes out of it